# Vagrant - Cannot execute "vagrant up" command on Mac

Tags: macos, vagrant, virtualbox

I am trying to execute "vagrant up" command. It was working until yesterday, but now I am getting following error:

> There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
>   for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.
>   Command: ["modifyvm", "7db01b4e-...", "--natpf1", "delete", "ssh"]

I'm on Mac OS. How do I fix it?

Comment: You might want to retag your post. It doesn't appear to have anything to do with the VMS family of operating systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you by any chance deleted the VM in "/Users//VirtualBox VMs" on your MacOS? 
If yes, then try this - Go to the directory where you executed "vagrant up" command from and remove .vagrant directory

> > rm -rf .vagrant/

When you execute "vagrant up" command, (I think that) the vagrant script looks for .vagrant directory, and if it finds the .vagrant directory, then it looks for the corresponding VM in "VirtualBox VMs" directory. And if you happened to have deleted the VM, you'll see the above error. By removing the .vagrant directory, you'll force the vagrant script to create a new .vagrant directory and associate a new VM with it.

Now try

> > vagrant up

Hopefully you will not see this error.

Comment: Awesome! This fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @StuartSmith If the answer resolves your problem, you should upvote it and accept it as answer. Take 2 minutes to see http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @LucM  -  The answer did resolve my question, but I'm new on stackoverflow and I don't have enough reputation to upvote the answer (or at least that's the error message I get).

Comment: @StuartSmith My bad!  You need 15 reputation to be able to upvote an answer.  I think there is no restriction to accept answer.by clicking on check mark under the number of vote of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I have similar problem with `vagrant up` command in Mac OS

```
Command: ["startvm", "a7c6ef51-dcce-4253-a761-b1e26ca8534b", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage: error: The virtual machine 'VagrantEnv_default_1562209910304_49097' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine
```

This article saved my life
https://medium.com/@Aenon/mac-virtualbox-kernel-driver-error-df39e7e10cd8

What you need to do is to open the `Security & Privacy` settings in your machine and then press `Allow` button for your Oracle software (virtual box).

Try vagrant up again and hopefully it's working now

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the `vagrant` command itself, it just did nothing. It turned out I had an alias called vagrant and hadn't removed it properly. I thought I did but I hadn't. The whole thing was driving me crazy. So in my case solution: check your `~/.bash_profile` and always double check you do `source ~/.bash_profile` on the command line.